# Feature importance in expectation maximization

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

The context is using EM algorithm for a mixture model - more precisely Dirichlet Multinomial Mixture, as discussed in [*Dirichlet Multinomial Mixtures: Generative Models for Microbial Metagenomics*](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0030126). One typically deals here with hundreds of samples and possibly dozens to hundreds of features, although only few of these features are considered important (in the context of the cited paper, it is several microbial genera, which are most prominently expressed in some of the mixture components.)

*Are there systematic ways of ranking the features according to their importance (when using EM)? Or selecting the essential combinations of features?*

E.g., I have found this paper: [*Gaussian mixture model with feature selection: An embedded approach*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360835220306707), but I don't have access to it, and I am not sure it presents a mainstream/solid enough approach to spend time on it.